# nextcloud SVG icon under activity is not shown in browser

Tags: apache, nextcloud

As you can see below, the svg icons are broken when opened in chrome. (The icon does not display in firefox)

Software:

FreeNas Jail - FreeBSD 11.1 Release

Apache 2.4

NextCloud 13.0.0

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this issue had to do with the nextcloud configuration. As the nextcloud is running behind proxy, the images are being sent from http to https causing a mixed content warning in the browser. In order to solve this issue, it is necessary to edit the nextcloud configuration as such.

```
'trusted_proxies' =>
  array (
    0 => '555.555.555.555',
  ),
'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://my.domain.tld',
'overwritecondaddr' => '^555\\.555\\.555\\.555$',
```

555.555.555.555 is the internal ip address of your proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

1. update to [NextCloud 13.0.1](https://nextcloud.com/changelog/) since this is the latest version of it now.
2. if the bug still exists create an issue in the [github nextcloud server repository](https://github.com/nextcloud/server).